# How do I traverse to the next position of an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a constructor which accepts a line of text such as "2 Street|Spain|Jamaica".

```
public Address(String lines) {
        arrOfStr = lines.split("[|]");

        streetName = arrOfStr[0];
        zone = arrOfStr[1];
        countryName = arrOfStr[2];
    }
```

And a method which gets the Country at the end of this String from the constructor

```
public String getCountry() {
    return countryName;
}
```

With a given input such as "2 Street|Spain||Jamaica" I would want to get the country name but the output only returns a blank space.

This was my attempt at getting the Country at the end of the String by making alterations to the constructor

```
public Address(String lines) {
        arrOfStr = lines.split("[|]");

        streetName = arrOfStr[0];
        zone = arrOfStr[1];
        if (countryName != " ") {
            countryName = arrOfStr[2];
        } else {
            countryName = arrOfStr[3];
        }

    }
```

Any assistance on how to get the country name?

Comment: Your first attempt seems like it should work. I don't understand your second attempt, though. First off, you don't compare strings with "==" or "!=", you use the equals method. Also, countryName should be null when you are in the constructor, so the else branch will never be reached.

Comment: This doesn't solve your issue, but you might consider this as a bit more readable---> lines.split(Pattern.quote("|"));

Comment: What does "Pattern.quote" do? And why is more readable than what I currently have? @David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly the last part of String is what `countryName` is. Would `countryName = arrOfStr[arrOfStr.length - 1]` be of help?